# Como fazer a soma e um count no MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tenho um `query` que trás o numero de linhas de uma determinada falha.

```
select falhas, 
       count(falhas) 
  from tabela 
 where semana = 'semana-5' 
 group by falhas 
 order by count(falhas) desc;
```

O resultado trás os valores abaixo:

```
3 
2 
1
1
1
```

Eu preciso somar o primeiro valor com o segundo, e a soma dos dois com o terceiro, e assim por diante. Alguém conhece uma maneira de fazer isso no `MySQL`.

o que eu queria que exibisse 3+2=5. pega o resultado 5+1 e por ai vai
linha1 exibe 5
linha2 exibe 6
linha3 exibe 7

ou uma maneira de quebra o mysql_fetch_array em string.

Comment: Diego, como ficaria o resultado que você espera? Seria simplesmente a soma dos valores, 3 + 2 + 1 + 1+ 1? Altere a pergunta e adicione como fica a resposta que você espera.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.falhas, SUM(a.falhas)
FROM tabela AS a, tabela AS b
WHERE a.id <= b.id
GROUP BY b.falhas
ORDER BY b.falhas DESC
```